# BSON functions affecting performance - installation dependent

Tags: python, django, pymongo, bson

I'm working with a reasonably complex Django application using MongoDB/pymongo.
On my local development environment, using the Django server, I'm getting decent performance.  When I move to remote server, running under Apache, there are pymongo/BSON methods that take up a huge amount of time.  These methods don't appear to be called *at all* in my local installation.  I'm having trouble finding the salient difference that is causing this change in PyMongo behavior.

Here's a selection of profiling from the remote server's call.  Again, these functions don't get called at all locally.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    ...
        684    0.007    0.000   10.042    0.015 __init__.py:497(decode_all)
 102704/735    1.193    0.000   10.035    0.014 __init__.py:325(_elements_to_dict)
546543/4233    2.549    0.000   10.025    0.002 __init__.py:314(_element_to_dict)
101969/1170    0.450    0.000    9.930    0.008 __init__.py:153(_get_object)
101448/1045    0.963    0.000    9.917    0.009 __init__.py:168(_get_array)
```

Comment: It turns out that the local machine being MacOS was relevant to the solution here. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by compiling PyMongo with C extensions.  The MacOS binary comes with these extensions automatically compiled in, Linux installations won't have them installed if dependencies aren't met.

Details are [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html).

In short - install the dependencies:

On Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

On RedHat:

```
sudo yum install gcc python-devel
```

Then reinstall PyMongo with:

```
pip install --upgrade pymongo
```

and enjoy the performance improvements.